# Is it best practice to provide a 3rd party vendor with Salesforce Admin account in setting up hubspot or any 3rd party applications

Tags: integration, admin, setup, system-admin

Is it a best practice to grant a Salesforce admin user account to a 3rd party vendor who's helping us in setting up hubspot for salesforce. I'm not completely sure if thats the right way or is there anything alternative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not recommend to provide any external entity admin access at all. But it also **depends** on how you view the 3rd party vendor here. If the 3rd party vendor is authorized to access your Org and is in compliance with your data access controls, they possibly Yes. But if it's all about installing a managed package, then you will most likely want to do that yourself/by the designated admin/developer for the Org.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks for the response. It is more than installing the managed package. How to make the 3rd party vendor in compliance with our data in Salesforce before  granting admin access?

Comment: That will depend which compliance policies your Organization follows and what type of data you have. It’s a very broad topic that can be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to limit access to only the entities required to do the tasks at hand.

Hubspot provides a permission set which can be created/deployed in your org and applied to a dedicated integration user account, which has been configured for no access to any org functionality beyond the bare minimum. At that point you grant access using the permission set to specific features in your org (adjusting as necessary to meet your org's data access requirements).

https://knowledge.hubspot.com/salesforce/install-the-hubspot-salesforce-integration

Comment: Thanks for the response. Good to know that hub spot's appexchange app after installation will provide permission sets which are just confined to the access they need. So do you want me to 1st install the app exchange product and then have the permission sets assigned to the dedicated hubspot_Salesforce integration user.